# How to authenticate facebook sdk without login dialog page?

Tags: php, facebook, cron, facebook-authentication

I am using Facebook SDK to post some test wall post on my own Facebook page. What i want is to post on my facebook page every 8 hours using PHP CRON script and for that i have to bypass the Facebook login dialog page, So does anyone know the way to authenticate from command line or on air?

Answer (score 2):

[Authenticating as a Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) will give you an access token which you can save it in your database and then perform various tasks using PHP.

This is helpful for doing various things using cron, Such as scheduling posts, maintain multiple pages, post to multiple pages at once, upload photos and lot of other activities using [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). Check their docs for more information on how to do that.

Note: You just have to authenticate your app once and save your page access token key, once you do this, you don't have to login again and you can just use your access token to perform various tasks on your page.

Comment: Yes, It will get expired. But you can extend the token by making an API call and get long-lived token (60 days validity max), then you can save it to your database.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook provide Access Token for a user to use the Facebook app. For the First time , user has to login through facebook login, after login to the site, it will ask the permission to access the App. Once User Accept then facebook will return you a code throgh url. You have to take the code and use that to get access token

by using following code

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=". $yourappId ."&redirect_uri=". urlencode($this->redirect_url) ."&client_secret=". $youappsecret."&code=". $code;
$auth_token = $this->getContents($url);

$str = explode('=',$auth_token);
$token = explode('&expires', $str[1]);
```

Here $token will have the access token of an user, u can store that token in ur local db and use that token to post a message to facebook wall. its simple.. thats all.

To Post a message on Fb Wall

```
$fb_id      = "User_fb_id"
$access_token   = "User_Access_Token_Take by Above code"
$msg        = "Message_to_post"
$img_path       = "Image_Path"      
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $this->appId, 
'secret' => $this->secret,
'cookie' => true));
if($msg != NULL) {
$attachment = array(
'message' => $msg,
'name' => 'NHM',                                                  
'picture' => $img_path);
} 
try {$result = $facebook->api('/'. $fb_id . '/feed/',
                                   'post',
                                    $attachment);

                if(isset($result['id'])) 
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
             } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
         }
```

Here you have to user Facebook User Id. To get User Id use the following Code

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=". $access_token;
$userInfo = $this->getContents($url);
$userInfo = json_decode($userInfo, true);


public function getContents($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
return $content;
}
```

Try this . Let me know If any issues

Comment: What is $this->getContents i can't find any method name like this in facebook SDK

Comment: I added the function getContents . Sorry for missing that one.

Comment: Instead of calling function , you can place the code Directly.

Comment: this gives me error: {"error":{"message":"redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.","type":"OAuthException","code":191}}

Comment: Problem in passing canvas url. Check ur canvas url both in Facebook application and ur code.. Give the url here..

Comment: i am not using canvas url anywhere..! and below is my code please let me know where am i wrong.

Comment: sorry the comment box doesn't allow me post more than 600 characters do you know any website where i can paste my code and share with you

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way to bypass the Facebook login dialog page, though for your case you can retrieve the extended access key and use the same for posting onto your wall.
You can use the following code using the PHP SDK to retrieve the access token

```
$extendedToken = $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$facebook->api('<PAGE_ID>?fields=access_token');
```

Then simply use

> $facebook->setAccessToken();

to post to your page. Remember to get the permission before you generate the extended access token.